# JsonMappingException - Unexpected Character in field name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialize JSON of format

```
"{mapping:{MyType(type=\"A\", value=\"B\"):\"C\"}}"
```

into a class type

```
class MyMapping {
    Map<MyType, String> mapping;
}

class MyType {
    String type;
    String value; 
}
```

Since I have a map type, i added a KeyDeserializer to deserialize `MyType(type=\"A\", value=\"B\")`

But when i try to deserialize this i get an exception

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('(' (code 40)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
```

This is because it encounters `(` in `MyType(type=\"A\", value=\"B\")` and it breaks there. If i put the  whole key within double quotes `\"MyType(type=\"A\", value=\"B\")\"`, it passes the the whole key to my deserializer.

Is there a way i can force it to escape the `'('` char without having to put the whole key with quotes.

Comment: Have you considered using a library like Gson

Comment: This is not a valid JSON so obviously it cannot be deserialied by standard deserializers...

Answer (score 0):

**The string in your example is not valid JSON.**

`"{mapping:{MyType(type=\"A\", value=\"B\"):\"C\"}}"`

You pointed out that the Jackson parser complains about the first (

If you want to use this particular string as a key you have to enclose it in quotes and escape internal quotes. Let's use a Javascript in a browser to do that, cause it's easy. From Chrome console...

```
> var c = {};
< undefined
> c['MyType(type="A", value="B")']='C';
< "C"
> JSON.stringify(c)
< "{"MyType(type=\"A\", value=\"B\")":"C"}"`
```

That's how Javascript escapes your key string as valid JSON.

**KeyDeserializer**

Based on Jackson 2.8 documentation for KeyDeserializer I would expect your KeyDeserializer to receive the whole key string. That's just how JSON works.

`{"key-string":"value")`

Of course "value" could be false, true, null or a number as well.

It's then up to you to parse the key-string and decide how to turn it into a key that your MyMapping can use.

**Your Key String Appears Easy to Parse**

Your KeyDeserializer can use a compiled regex pattern to get the two key properties as two regex 'groups'.

**What if you don't want to parse the key string?**

It sounds like you don't want to parse this key. There are several ways to avoid this. One key to this is to use a JSON format that makes it easy, such as ...

`{"key":{"keyType":"A","keyValue":"B"}, "value":"C"}`

Then you could use annotations to teach Jackson to work with your MyMapping class.

Such as (untested, just a sketch)

```
class MyMapping {
    Map<MyType, String> mapping;
    @JsonCreator
    public MyMapping(Map<String,Object> input) {
        Map<String,Object> key = (Map)input.get("key");
        String value = (String)input.get("value");
        MyType myKey = new MyType(key);
        mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put(myKey,value);
    }
}

class MyType {
    String type;
    String value; 
    MyType (Map<String,Object> input) {
        type = (String)input.getOrDefault("key","");
        value = (String)input.getOrDefault("value","");
    }
}
```

There's a very long list of problems with this example. You will be using the default object address based comparison in the Map, for example. I made this code short by ignoring likely ClassCastExceptions and other data problems. But the point here was not to write good code, or to try to understand the requirements,  but simply to point out how you can get Jackson to parse the JSON for you.

There are many. other ways to achieve that. I just. picked the first one that came to mind.